# NGINX crashed and weird logs on access.log

Tags: nginx, logging, scripting, python

When I came back home just now, I was checking my webserver if it was still running and I noticed that my NGINX server was not running anymore.

I tried to restart my NGINX a few times by running the command
`$ NGINX` and these error's occured:

```
2023/02/11 22:01:54 [emerg] 2394#2394: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:01:54 [emerg] 2394#2394: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:01:54 [emerg] 2394#2394: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:01:54 [emerg] 2394#2394: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:01:54 [emerg] 2394#2394: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:01:54 [emerg] 2394#2394: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:01:54 [emerg] 2394#2394: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:01:54 [emerg] 2394#2394: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:01:54 [emerg] 2394#2394: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:01:54 [emerg] 2394#2394: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:01:54 [emerg] 2394#2394: still could not bind()
2023/02/11 22:02:19 [emerg] 2454#2454: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:02:19 [emerg] 2454#2454: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:02:19 [emerg] 2454#2454: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:02:19 [emerg] 2454#2454: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:02:19 [emerg] 2454#2454: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:02:19 [emerg] 2454#2454: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:02:19 [emerg] 2454#2454: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:02:19 [emerg] 2454#2454: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:02:19 [emerg] 2454#2454: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:02:19 [emerg] 2454#2454: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:02:19 [emerg] 2454#2454: still could not bind()
2023/02/11 22:03:09 [emerg] 2484#2484: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:03:09 [emerg] 2484#2484: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:03:09 [emerg] 2484#2484: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:03:09 [emerg] 2484#2484: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:03:09 [emerg] 2484#2484: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
2023/02/11 22:03:09 [emerg] 2484#2484: still could not bind()
```

Then I looked at my error.log file and saw that there were some errors around a certain time:

```
2023/02/11 20:21:56 [error] 1877#1877: *29 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/.env" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /.env HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:56 [error] 1877#1877: *30 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/.env.prod" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /.env.prod HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:56 [error] 1877#1877: *31 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/.env.dev" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /.env.dev HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:56 [error] 1877#1877: *32 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/sendgrid.env" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /sendgrid.env HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:56 [error] 1877#1877: *33 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/.aws/credentials" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /.aws/credentials HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:56 [error] 1877#1877: *34 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/config.py" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /config.py HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:56 [error] 1877#1877: *35 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/docker-compose.yml" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /docker-compose.yml HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:56 [error] 1877#1877: *36 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/docker/docker-compose.yml" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /docker/docker-compose.yml HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:56 [error] 1877#1877: *37 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/config/settings.yml" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /config/settings.yml HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:56 [error] 1877#1877: *38 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/app/config/settings.yml" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /app/config/settings.yml HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:57 [error] 1877#1877: *39 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/config/parameters.yml" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /config/parameters.yml HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:57 [error] 1877#1877: *40 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/app/config/parameters.yml" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /app/config/parameters.yml HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:57 [error] 1877#1877: *41 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/config.php-dist" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /config.php-dist HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:57 [error] 1877#1877: *42 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/application.ini" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /application.ini HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:57 [error] 1877#1877: *43 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/application/application.ini" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /application/application.ini HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:57 [error] 1877#1877: *44 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/configs/application.ini" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /configs/application.ini HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:57 [error] 1877#1877: *45 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/config/application.ini" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /config/application.ini HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:57 [error] 1877#1877: *46 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/application/configs/application.ini" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /application/configs/application.ini HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:58 [error] 1877#1877: *66 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/.git/config" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /.git/config HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:58 [error] 1877#1877: *67 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/demo/.git/config" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /demo/.git/config HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:58 [error] 1877#1877: *68 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/dev/.git/config" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /dev/.git/config HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:58 [error] 1877#1877: *69 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/web/.git/config" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /web/.git/config HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:58 [error] 1877#1877: *70 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/api/.git/config" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /api/.git/config HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:58 [error] 1877#1877: *71 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/admin/.git/config" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /admin/.git/config HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
2023/02/11 20:21:58 [error] 1877#1877: *72 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/app/.git/config" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.91.160.194, server: , request: "GET /app/.git/config HTTP/1.1", host: "45.132.242.78"
```

What was weird, because the server is not serving anything real yet, so the only one who would make request would be me and I was not home at that time. So I took a look to my access.log file and saw some strange Python requests:

```
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:56 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:56 +0000] "GET /.env.prod HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:56 +0000] "GET /.env.dev HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:56 +0000] "GET /sendgrid.env HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:56 +0000] "GET /.aws/credentials HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:56 +0000] "GET /config.py HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:56 +0000] "GET /docker-compose.yml HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:56 +0000] "GET /docker/docker-compose.yml HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:56 +0000] "GET /config/settings.yml HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:56 +0000] "GET /app/config/settings.yml HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /config/parameters.yml HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /app/config/parameters.yml HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /config.php-dist HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /application.ini HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /application/application.ini HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /configs/application.ini HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /config/application.ini HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /application/configs/application.ini HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /.env HTTP/1.1" 400 264 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /.env.prod HTTP/1.1" 400 264 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /.env.dev HTTP/1.1" 400 264 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /sendgrid.env HTTP/1.1" 400 264 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /.aws/credentials HTTP/1.1" 400 264 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /config.py HTTP/1.1" 400 264 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /docker-compose.yml HTTP/1.1" 400 264 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /docker/docker-compose.yml HTTP/1.1" 400 264 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /config/settings.yml HTTP/1.1" 400 264 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /app/config/settings.yml HTTP/1.1" 400 264 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /config/parameters.yml HTTP/1.1" 400 264 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /app/config/parameters.yml HTTP/1.1" 400 264 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /config.php-dist HTTP/1.1" 400 264 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /application.ini HTTP/1.1" 400 264 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:57 +0000] "GET /application/application.ini HTTP/1.1" 400 264 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:58 +0000] "GET /configs/application.ini HTTP/1.1" 400 264 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:58 +0000] "GET /config/application.ini HTTP/1.1" 400 264 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:58 +0000] "GET /application/configs/application.ini HTTP/1.1" 400 264 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:58 +0000] "GET /.git/config HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:58 +0000] "GET /demo/.git/config HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:58 +0000] "GET /dev/.git/config HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:58 +0000] "GET /web/.git/config HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:58 +0000] "GET /api/.git/config HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:58 +0000] "GET /admin/.git/config HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
54.91.160.194 - - [11/Feb/2023:20:21:58 +0000] "GET /app/.git/config HTTP/1.1" 404 134 "-" "python-requests/2.28.2"
```

Is this someone who was trying to break in? Or is this a bot or something else?

This is my server set-up: Is it setup well?

```
server {
    if ($host = www.backstrapp.nl) {
        return 301 https://www.backstr.app$request_uri;
    }

    if ($host = backstrapp.nl) {
        return 301 https://www.backstr.app$request_uri;
    }

     if ($host = backstr.app) {
         return 301 https://www.backstr.app$request_uri;
     }

     if ($host = www.backstr.app) {
         return 301 https://www.backstr.app$request_uri;
     }

     if ($host = api.backstr.app) {
         return 301 https://api.backstr.app$request_uri;
     }
}

server {
    server_name www.backstr.app;
    location / {
        root /var/www/backstrapp/client;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/backstr.app/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/backstr.app/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    server_name api.backstr.app;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8800;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/backstr.app/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/backstr.app/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
  listen        80 default_server;
  server_name   _;
  return        444; # "Connection closed without response"
}
```

Let me know! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this a bot?

Yes.

All public IPv4 addresses on the internet get
scanned by script kiddies all the time.
Stay patched! `apt upgrade` is your friend.

> tried to restart my NGINX a few times

> ```
> bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
> ```

That is EADDRINUSE.
You have another daemon process bound to port 80.
Likely it is a leftover nginx that hasn't quite
died yet. Kill it, or kill -9, or reboot if need be,
and then your newly configured nginx will be
happy to acquire the port.

Track it down with `$ sudo lsof -i:80`

---

Longer term, consider configuring a
packet filter to reduce the noise level:

```
# apt install fail2ban
```

Comment: Okay, clear. Thanks for the answer I will have a look to the fail2ban module

Answer (score 0):

J_H's answer is correct about the bot aspect. However, an additional comment:

> This is my server set-up: Is it setup well?

It is best to not use `if` whenever possible. Therefore your redirects should be implemented like this:

```
server {
    server_name www.backstrapp.nl backstrapp.nl ...;

    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;

    return 301 https://www.backstr.app$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I think Certbot implements this automatically. I will give it a go. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Ah yes, certbot unfortunately has this odd structure.